# Android Studio update duplicates Java and res folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio to the latest `3.5` version. After update and restart, the project at which I'm working got java and res (generated). Why? How to get rid/hide this new generated folders?

[image]

Comment: please read the release notes of Android studio `3.5`

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I've read but I coundn't find something relevant. Can you please indicate me where is something related specified?

Comment: get rid of them? Why?

Comment: @TimCastelijns To have the exact same structure of my project as before. Why to have those duplicates java and res (generated)?

Comment: Do you really think Google got bored and decided to randomly duplicate folders for no good reason? You have to keep those generated files else you can't compile your app. You should ask a different question and that is how to hide those from your IDE.

Comment: I just updated to AD 3.5 and checked on git. There are no new files generated for me (or at least nothing that I could see). To me it looks more like they have been there before anyway but just were not that (dominantly) visible. In any case they are required so no use in getting rid of them.

Comment: @Zun No, I don't think that way. Ok then, How to get rid/hide this new generated folders? Also edited my question.

Comment: @TobiasReich So you say that is the normal behaviour and there is no solution?

Comment: *there is no solution?* the opposite actually. There is no problem. Also they are not visible in git because `/gen` is ignored by default

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks you for that. Yes, you're right, they are not visible in git.

Comment: In any case, they get generated for a reason. If you have a look there, you see it's the BuildConfig and those type of files. So you don't want to delete them anyway - even if they were new files.

Answer (score 1):

try clean project

Navigation:

> Build > Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this: "Invalidate caches/Restart"